# ruby unintended variable assignment/change

Tags: ruby, variables, variable-assignment

i'm quite a layman in programming and a noob to ruby but find it useful for my work anyway. Cuirrently I work on a rather large script which brought the following unintended effect:

```
def my_reduce_method(value_hash,some_keys)
  value_hash.delete(some_keys) 
end

puts all_values
=> all_values

some_values = all_values # start my block with all values (class: hash)

some_values = my_reduce_method(some_values,keys_to_reduce) 
# here only some_values should be effected!

puts all_values
=> some_values
```

Right in the block there is no damage, but the original all_values is lost! How can I ensure that in a certain code block a certain variable is definitely not changed?

Thank you in advance for any input!!!

Comment: Nothing in the code you posted will modify `all_values`, so I'm guessing something in `my_reduce_method` is modifying it.

Comment: It's a shallow copy of all_values. That's the problem. my_reduce_method is modifying some_values, which is pointing to the same data that all_values points to.

Comment: There was no good reason for the downvote. Most appropriate question from first-time poster I've seen.

Comment: @Plasmarob, and, as usual, no explanation/justification provided for the downvote.

Comment: @Cary I think there are people that honestly think they can rise to the top by downvoting everyone. Like intentional injury in sports. Because they can.

Comment: An easy way to make of a deep copy of any object `o` that can be `dup`'ed: `Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(o))`.

Comment: All this time an no one's ever brought up Marshal to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All object assignments in Ruby are reference assignments.

That means, when you do:

```
some_values = all_values
```

You're copying the reference(or address) of the object which `all_values` is referencing(or pointing).

The solution for your case is simple:

```
some_values = all_values.clone
```

`.dup` also works usually (can be different depending on the object).

Another thing to be careful about is, when `all_values[:x]` has a string and you do:

```
some_values = all_values.clone
some_values[:x] += 'abc'
```

This will not change `all_values[:x]` because `some_values[:x]` gets (is assigned) a new string object.

But if you do:

```
some_values = all_values.clone
some_values[:x] << 'abc'
```

Both `all_values[:x]` and `some_values[:x]` change, because they both reference the same string object.

This is the effect of the **shallow copy** @Plasmarob mentioned.

Comment: Strings are references too.

Comment: How kind of you to credit. Someday I'd like to see SO implement a clean interface for people to merge their answers and ownership.

Comment: Ditto, ditto, and ditto.

Comment: @Plasmarob My point is, .clone and .dup also make shallow copies. Thanks for the kind comment though.

Comment: @jaeheung It's nice to see intelligent conversation on SO - I hope you never leave. We need more helpers like you - and less critics.

Comment: Speaking of which, how do clone and dup relate to .new?

Comment: @jaeheung: Strings are mutable and as such aren't copied when you assign them to a variable. They just get a new reference. Both variables then point to the same String object (as verified by its `object_id`)

Comment: @Holger You're right. I was wrong about the string being copied on assignment. Thank you for pointing out. I'm updating my answer.

Comment: @sergio Sorry, it was me who was confused by testing it incorrectly.

Comment: @jaeheung: Thanks, it worked exactly as it should! BTW what became of the solution Hash.new(all_values) and why is it wrong?

Comment: @bobito `Hash.new(obj)` is not a copy constructor. The `obj` is used as the default value of new elements of the new Hash.

Answer (score 0):

Object#clone preserves the frozen attribute and singleton methods. If you
don't need those, what happens to your example, Object#dup is sufficient.